# Cómo integrar filas en un marco de datos a partir de valores de una columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo [un dataframe `df1`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15OU7SwaxqW4vds3E2uN-exPiXOQg2bMJmrGcxIYalaI/edit?usp=sharing):

```py
   QID Questions    B Answer1 Answer2 Answer3  F  G  H  I  J
0    3         a  4.0       a       a       a  a  e  g  i  l
1    4         b  5.0       b       b       b  a  r  h  m  p
2    5         d  5.0     NaN       e       d  b  u  e  i  z
3    6         e  5.0       d       h       r  b  c  z  i  3
```

Y [una otra, `new_dataframe`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-fecLRvgTpAZ9UmPk_lQ4gFnTFIvoA6p/view?usp=sharing) que me gustaria anadir entre las líneas de `df_1`.

```
    QID    Questions    B   Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 F G H I J
2   4_1 z   5.0 b   k   b   a   r   h   m   p
3   4_2 w   4.0 b   k   b   c   r   h   m   p
```

En efecto, me gustaria obtener:

```
    QID    Questions    B   Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 F G H I J
0   3   a   4.0 a   a   a   a   e   g   i   l    
1   4   b   5.0 b   b   b   a   r   h   m   p
2   4_1 z   5.0 b   k   b   a   r   h   m   p
3   4_2 w   4.0 b   k   b   c   r   h   m   p
4   5   d   5.0 NaN e   d   b   u   e   i   z
5   6   e   5.0 d   h   r   b   c   z   i   3
...
```

Así que quiero integrar las líneas del segundo marco de datos `new_dataframe` cuyo QID está compuesto por un dígito y un sub-dígito, siguiendo las líneas de `df1`. Por ejemplo las lineas en `new_dataframe` cuales QID son `4_1`, `4_2` ... deve integrarse despues de `4`.

Hasta hoy intenté lo siguiente:

```
from natsort import index_natsorted as ins
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read the files
df1 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Auspex/QuestionBank_06082020_QGrid_and_CINT.csv", dtype={'QID': str}, low_memory=False)
df1.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Auspex/new_df.csv', dtype={'QID': str})
df2.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

# concat them
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# sort the values using the key parameter in sort_values
df.sort_values(by='QID', key=lambda col: np.argsort(ins(col))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d9f848d1f6bf> in <module>()
     14 
     15 # sort the values using the key parameter in sort_values
---> 16 df.sort_values(by='QID', key=lambda col: np.argsort(ins(col))).reset_index(drop=True)

TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero unos cambios en tu código, checa los comments que he agregado...

```
from natsort import natsorted #natsorted te ayuda en lo que necesitas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Al momento de concatenar haz que `QID`sea tu index

```
# concat them
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).set_index('QID', drop=False)
```

Finalmente ordenas por index (QID) para que sea más eficiente el trabajo

```
df.index = natsorted(df["QID"])
```

El resultado de los primeros 10 rows es:

```
QID 
0
0R 
1
2
4
5
5R 
6
7
8
Name: QID, dtype: object
```

El resultado de los últimos 10 registros:

```
QID 
2545_9 
2562_1 
2562_2 
2562_3 
2562_4 
2562_5 
2562_6 
2562_7 
2562_8 
2562_9
Name: QID, dtype: object
```

Comment: Estoy confundido @Adrian, me parece que mas allá de una sugerencia, es una completa respuesta funcional que solventa la pregunta. ¿En qué parte crees que debo mejorar lo que puse? Gracias.

Comment: Perdona, he confundido. +1

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu feedback.